# Random Image Orientation xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, image

Is there a way to create a random image orientation? I want my app to choose a photo and randomize the orientation on the view.

Comment: Not clear to me. Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there are only four orientations an image can be in...

```
NSArray *orientationDegrees = @[ @0, @90, @180, @270 ];
int randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(orientationDegrees.count);
NSNumber *randomOrientation = orientationDegrees[randomNumber];
```